# What column partial text is found

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYiZB.png)I have multiple categories, each of which has some values. In my sheet, I am trying to find what "category" a specific cell contains. The range would contain the partial text of the cell however.

Basically, my if statement is if e4 contains an "*M*" then it = v2, if not then check $g$2:$v15 to see if any of those values are matches or partial matches of c4, and if none of them are found, then u2.

I have attempted index:match, if/countifs, I continually get the #N/A result, regardless of my attempt at a formula.

Clearly, I'm new to this:

This is what I'm hoping to yield with the formula

Comment: If looking through a single column, you can use MATCH with a wildcard: `=MATCH("*M*",G2:G15,)`

Comment: Cybernetic, I'm looking through multiple columns.  Here is what my current function looks like.... =IF(COUNTIF(E3,"*M*"),$V$2,INDEX($G$2:$V$15,MATCH(C3&"*",$G$2:$V$15,-1)))